# How to stop service when Clear Data is pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

When user using the Settings' Clear Data button I get the following message:

> ActivityManager(201): Scheduling restart of crashed service

How can I kill the service when Cleadr Data pressed?
How can I detect this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this solution is correct or not. Is it possible to save something to Sharedpreferences in onDestroy and again in onStartService check whether the data is there in sharedpreferences or not. If there don't start service or kill Service.